# Drop a group of rows if one column has missing data in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
df

          Group       Dist
    0     A             5
    1     B             2
    2     A             3
    3     B             1
    4     B             0
    5     A             5
```

I am trying to drop all rows that match `Group` if the `Dist` column equals zero. This works to delete row 4:

```
df = df[df.Dist != 0]
```

however I also want to delete rows 1 and 3 so I am left with:

```
df
          Group       Dist
    0     A             5
    2     A             3
    5     A             5
```

Any ideas on how to drop the group based off this condition?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First get all `Group` values for `Entry == 0` and then filter out them by check column `Group` with inverted mask by `~`:

```
df1 = df[~df['Group'].isin(df.loc[df.Dist == 0, 'Group'])]
print (df1)
  Group   Dist
0     A      5
2     A      3
5     A      5
```

Or you can use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with [`GroupBy.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.all.html) for test if groups has no `0` values:

```
df1 = df[(df.Dist != 0).groupby(df['Group']).transform('all')]
```

EDIT: For remove all groups with missing values:

```
df2 = df[df['Dist'].notna().groupby(df['Group']).transform('all')]
```

For test missing values:

```
print (df[df['Dist'].isna()])
```

if return nothing there are no missing values `NaN` or no `None` like Nonetype.

So is possible check scalar, e.g. if this value is in row with index `10`:

```
print (df.loc[10, 'Dist'])
print (type(df.loc[10, 'Dist']))
```

Comment: Sorry @jezrael i just fixed the description to have `Dist` as the heading

Comment: @SOK - No problem, renamed too ;)

Comment: would that also work in a `dropna` function. EG `df.dropna(subset=['Dist']).groupby(df['Group']).transform('all')`?

Comment: @SOK - Do yo uneed test if no missing value per group? then use `df['Dist'].notna().groupby(df['Group']).transform('all')`

Comment: Ah yes, perfect. I just need to drop all rows in the group if there is a na

Comment: Sorry @jezrael, how do i delete all rows from the same group where a different column has a na value? that suggestion above didnt work (i have a bigger table of 20 columns)

Comment: @SOK - Do you need test all columns? Or some columns in list `cols = ['col1','col2','col3']` ?

Comment: Just one column usually at different stages in the process

Comment: @SOK - So `df['Dist'].notna().groupby(df['Group']).transform('all')` not working? Then can you test if there is missing values? Or empty strings or `nan`s strings? Yoiu can test it by `df[df['Dist'].isna()]` for get rows with misisng values

Answer (score 1):

You can use `groupby` and the method [`filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html#pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter):

```
df.groupby('Group').filter(lambda x: x['Dist'].ne(0).all())
```

Output:

```
  Group  Dist
0     A     5
2     A     3
5     A     5
```

If you want to filter out groups with missing values:

```
df.groupby('Group').filter(lambda x: x['Dist'].notna().all())
```

Comment: thanks! I tried the below answer and it worked. Could i adapt this for `na` values do you think?

Comment: dropping a the `Group` rows if `Dist` is `na`

Comment: Use `x['Dist'].notna().all()` instead.